# What is the proper way to see rails application's web site statistics?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, statistics, visitor-statistic

I want to see how many people are visiting my pages, what is the proper way of tracking a rails application?

Comment: what's wrong with google analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

> Segment.io

Segment.io’s integrations with Mixpanel, Klaviyo, Google Analytics, and many others.
[reference url](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/segment-io-and-ruby)

> Google Analytics
>
> [Mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com/?from=adwords-mp1&gclid=CPvt4s2228cCFRGeGwodOlMFBQ)
>
> [KISSMetrics](https://kissmetrics.com/)
>
> [ahoy](http://ankane.github.io/ahoy/)

from awesome-ruby

> Analytical - Gem for managing multiple analytics services in your
> rails app.
>
> FnordMetric - A ruby/redis framework for collecting and visualizing
> timeseries data. It enables you to build beautiful real-time analytics
> dashboards within minutes.
>
> Gabba - Simple way to send server-side notifications to Google
> Analytics.
>
> Impressionist - Rails Plugin that tracks impressions and page views.
>
> Legato - Model analytics reports and queries against the official
> Google Analytics Reporting API.
>
> Rack::Tracker - Rack middleware that can be hooked up to multiple
> services and exposing them in a unified fashion.
>
> Staccato - Track analytics into the official Google Analytics
> Collection API.

[Other gems list](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Web_Analytics)

Comment: praaveen, do you know some good tuts/screencasts on setting up rails + segment ? The ones I find are pretty confusing. Can't even decide to implement it on frontend or backend.

Comment: more links https://coderwall.com/p/b_oqtq/server-side-events-with-segment-io-for-free
https://robots.thoughtbot.com/segment-io-and-ruby
http://railsapps.github.io/rails-google-analytics.html